# Convert Map<Long, MyObject> to Map<Long, List<MyObject>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

using java8 and the stream api.

There is only one MyObject, and I want to convert

```
Map<Long, MyObject>
```

to

```
Map<Long, List<MyObject>>
```

where the list has one element ?

Comment: If you are only going to have one key, why use map? And not a set instead?

Comment: @ManuelS One value, not one key.

Comment: There is only one MyObject...den why do u want to use List<MyObject> ??

Comment: I suggest you take a look at Guava MultiMap. Its is a Google library that offers a really good approach to that data structure. Take a look at [this](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html) post for examples.

Comment: @SarithaG for many many reasons. Do you need to know the api I am producing for, or all the business requirements sitting on my deak to answer the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<Long, List<MyObject>> newMap = oldMap.entrySet().stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Entry::getKey, 
                            e -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(e.getValue()))));
```

If immutable list in value is okay, the last line may be simplified a bit:

```
                            e -> Collections.nCopies(1, e.getValue())));
```

Comment: This lambda expression is maybe a bit over the top for OP as he seems to be a beginner, but answer is still valid and correct. +1

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg OP has a gold java badge, I don't think he is so green.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Long, MyObject> yourMap = whateverYouImplementedHere;
Map<Long, List<MyObject>> listMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Entry<Long, MyObject> entry : yourMap.entrySet()){

    listMap.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<MyObject>(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: This would solve OP's general question, though other data structures are a lot better

Comment: this makes no use of java 8 stream features

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the entry set stream and use the `toMap` collector combined with `Collections.singletonList` (which creates an immutable list) to create new values from the original map.

```
Map<Long, List<MyObject>> transformedMap = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                      e -> Collections.singletonList(e.getValue())));
```